# Как сделать сортировку в каждом вложенном массиве, сначало на количество элементов внутреннего массива,а потом сравнить элементы между собой?

Tags: javascript

```js
const array = [1,3,5,4,5,7]

let validArr = (arr) =>{
  if(arr.length>=3){
    return arr
  }else{
    console.log("Array don't have enough elements,at least shoud be 3 numbers")
  }
}

let arrayIntoChunks = (arr) => {
  let chunkSize = 3;
  let resultOfValidArr = validArr(arr);
  let resultArrayIntoChunks = []
  
  for(let i = 0;i<resultOfValidArr.length;i++){
    const chunked = resultOfValidArr.slice(i,i+chunkSize)
    resultArrayIntoChunks.push(chunked)
  }
  return resultArrayIntoChunks
}

let checkForNestedArrays = (arr) =>{
  let resultArrayIntoChunks = arrayIntoChunks(arr)
  let resultCheckForNestedArrays = []
  
  
  for(let i = 0;i<resultArrayIntoChunks.length;i++){
   if(resultArrayIntoChunks[i].length < 3){
     let index = indexOf(resultArrayIntoChunks[i])
     return resultArrayIntoChunks.splice(index)
   }else{
     return resultArrayIntoChunks
   }
  }
}

console.log(checkForNestedArrays(array))
```

У меня получилось разложить один общий массив на несколько маленьких, но как мне теперь внутри общего большого массива проверить каждый вложенный массив на количество вложенных элементов,а потом с теми которые остались сделать проверку внутри них.
Как показано на картинке[image: Задача]

Comment: Что означает "RESULT"?
Если массив сортирован слева направо , то 0 ,иначе 1?

Comment: Забыл сказать,что я должен принять исходный массив  и вернуть массив ,в котором после проверки каждого вложенного массива будет результат 1 если вложенный массив соответствует условиям x>y<z ,x<y>z. И 0 если вложенный массив не соответсвует выше условиям.

Comment: А если размер чанка будет 4 или 5?

Comment: Чанк только 3 может быть,в этом и суть,что мне нужно выкинуть массивы после чанка которые меньше 3 элементов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спрашивайте, если что-то непонятно

```js
const array = [1,3,5,4,5,7]

let validArr = (arr) =>{
  if(arr.length>=3){
    return arr
  }else{
    console.log("Array don't have enough elements,at least shoud be 3 numbers")
  }
}

let arrayIntoChunks = (arr) => {
  let chunkSize = 3;
  let resultOfValidArr = validArr(arr);
  let resultArrayIntoChunks = []
  
  for(let i = 0;i<resultOfValidArr.length;i++){
    const chunked = resultOfValidArr.slice(i,i+chunkSize)
    ////Начало моего кода ,чтобы убрать чанки у которых размер меньше 3
    if(chunked.length>=chunkSize){ 
        resultArrayIntoChunks.push(chunked)
    } 
    ///Конец Моего кода   
    
    
  }
  return resultArrayIntoChunks
}

let checkForNestedArrays = (arr) =>{
  let resultArrayIntoChunks = arrayIntoChunks(arr)
  let resultCheckForNestedArrays = []
  
  
  for(let i = 0;i<resultArrayIntoChunks.length;i++){
   if(resultArrayIntoChunks[i].length < 3){
     let index = indexOf(resultArrayIntoChunks[i])
     return resultArrayIntoChunks.splice(index)
   }else{
     return resultArrayIntoChunks
   }
  }
}
////Начало моего кода
let result = (arr)=>{
  let res = [];
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     if((arr[i][0]>arr[i][1] && arr[i][1]<arr[i][2]) || (arr[i][0]<arr[i][1] && arr[i][1]>arr[i][2])){  ////x>y<z или x<y>z.
       res.push(1);
     }else{
       res.push(0);
     }
  }
  return res;
  
}

let chunkedArr = checkForNestedArrays(array);
//////КОНЕЦ моего кода
console.log(result(chunkedArr));
```

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, я в функции checkForNestedArrays хотел профильтровать вложенные массивы по количеству элементов в массиве ,я честно думал что у меня нерабочая эта проверка.Темболее ты уже исключил из массивы маленькие вложенные массивы строкой : if(chunked.length>=chunkSize){ 
        resultArrayIntoChunks.push(chunked)
    } Зачем тогда нужна функция checkForNestedArrays и ты использовал её в конце,спасибо!

Comment: Я в код особо не вчитывался, именно вот эта функция мне показалась очень уж странной , сейчас я понял что можно её вообще исключить отсюда. А в конце использовать просто:

chunkedArr = arrayIntoChunks(array);
console.log(result(chunkedArr));

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь и отклик!=)

Comment: @Daniil галочка и стрелочка слева от ответа)